# Array to string conversion, How to get array values in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel

How can i get address and latitude from this array in Laravel

```
locations: [
  {
    is_return: 0,
    address: "26 Monrovia St, Wuse, Abuja, Nigeria",
    latitude: "9.080832",
    …
  },
  …
]0: {
  is_return: 0,
  address: "26 Monrovia St, Wuse, Abuja, Nigeria",
  latitude: "9.080832",
  …
}]
```

When i try like this `$request->locations[0]->is_return;` it returns an error `Array to string conversion`..pls someone help

Comment: do u have another method?

Answer (score 0):

okay i got the solution..

i picked like this, to help anyone that may come across this

$request->locations[0]['address'];

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin There's a waiting period of 2 days before a self-answered question can be marked as accepted. They will when they can.